# Building successfully done despite errors in the code - Swift Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode

I am confused, whenever I have an error in my Swift code, the building of the app in the simulator fails.

Today, even though I am pretty sure the code is correct (and it works), I see a few errors in my code, and even so, the app-building is successful in the simulator.

Anyone has run into this before? How can I fix it?

Thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TM6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but have you tried restarting Xcode?

Comment: I have, and the errors are still there, and the code still works!

Comment: and I imagine you've already cleaned, and deleted the derived data folder?

Comment: hmm.. no! but interestingly, the day after the code stopped working. so the unusual bug is not anymore there, and I am trying to fix my code.

Comment: ‍♂️ Oh, Xcode